# Is there a reason why vector graphics objects in my scene are being scaled up in android build of my game but not in mac build?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vector-graphics

I'm setting up a vector sprite in my game and using it as an object in the scene. I have scaled it to look how I want and it works well both in unity and when I build it for mac. However, when I build an android apk for it, the object strangely scales up and covers the screen. Here's an image of my SVG sprite settings and my android build settings.[svg asset settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoXia.png).[android build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO8dN.png)